# How to add/remove a class to an element which has multiple classes?

Tags: javascript, html

What's the best and easy way to add/remove a class to an element which has **several classes**? I want to do that in pure javascript. I've seen some topics but there was no single solution which **everyone** agrees **to use de-facto**. Is there any? Or should I just iterate over all the class, remember them and them add/remove one? Is there more simple and straightforward solution in pure javascript?

Comment: have you searched on the web?

Comment: While this *can* be answered in a purely theoretical manner it would be far more useful to you, and others in the future, if you gave a specific snippet of HTML, and the JavaScript you're using to retrieve any given element, for us to demonstrate upon, That way you have a concrete example and we don't have to manufacture one for you.

Comment: @Manish, open your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by,

```
elm = document.getElementById("Id");
elm.classList.add("class","name","all"); //to add
elm.classList.remove("class","name","all"); //to remove
```

I would request you to read JavaScript documentations/tutorials, its the first thing you will see in any tutorials.

- [W3CSchool](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)
- [Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)
- [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-classlist-api/)

Comment: that doesn't work in all browsers.

Comment: @ako25, most browsers do. Are you worried about IE10 and lower?

Comment: @putvande, yes.

Comment: @ako25 so implement helper function, 2 lines of code with regex.

Comment: @dfsq, ... how?

Comment: With `String.prototype.replace` on `className` property.